# Validation always coming back false

Tags: validation, cakephp

why is my model taking it consistently to return false everytime I try input two names into my database. here is my entire model. All I'm doing is checking to see that both to/biller, partytwo/partyone exist in the relationship table. when i check debug kit, it shows that the form is taking in the correct variables but when I check this->validationErrors - it comes back as nothing? please help.

```
class Invoice extends AppModel{ 
        var $name='Invoice'; 
        public $useTable = 'invoices';
        public $primaryKey = 'id';
        public $belongsTo = array(
        'Relationship' =>array(
            'className' => 'Relationship',
            'foreignKey' =>'relationship_id',
            )
        ); 
        var $validate = array(
            'to' => array(
                'relationshipExists' => array(
                    'rule' => array(
                        'relationshipExists',
                        ),
                    'message' => 'sorry you dont have a relationship with that user.'
                    ),
                ),
            );

        public function relationshipExists($check){ 
            $relationshipExists=$this->Relationship->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Relationship.partyone','Relationship.partytwo'=>$check)));
                if ($relationshipExists == true) {
                    return TRUE;
                    }
                else
                    return FALSE;
                    }}
```

-relationship model

```
<?php

class Relationship extends AppModel
{

    var $name = 'Relationship';
    public $useTable = 'relationships_users';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Invoice' =>
            array(
                'className'              => 'Invoice',
                'joinTable'              => 'invoice',
                'foreignKey'             => 'invoice_id'));
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' =>array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' =>'partyone','partytwo',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'username',
            )); 

    var $validate = array(
        'date' => array(
            'rule' => array(
                'datevalidation',
                'systemDate'
            ),
            'message' => 'Current Date and System Date is mismatched'
        ),
        'partytwo' => array(
            'userExists' => array(
                'rule' => array(
                    'userExists',
                ),
                'message' => 'That username doesnt exist.'
            ),
        ),
    );

    function datevalidation($field = array(), $compare_field = null)
    {
        if ($field['date'] > $compare_field)
            return TRUE;
        else
            return FALSE;
    }

    function userExists($check)
    {   
        $userExists = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions' => array('User.username'=>$check)));
        if ($userExists == 1) {
           return TRUE;
        }
        else
            return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your find is going to do interesting things...

```
$relationshipExists=$this->Relationship->find('count', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Relationship.partyone',
    'Relationship.partytwo' => $check
  )
));
```

This would probably produce something similar to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM relationships as Relationship 
  WHERE Relationship.partyone = 0
  AND Relationship.partytwo = Array;
```

This is because you're passing nothing to Relationship.partyone and an array to partytwo. You'll need to change it to something like this:

```
$relationshipExists=$this->Relationship->find('count', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Relationship.partyone <>' => null,
    'Relationship.partytwo' => current($check) // get the value from the passed var
  )
));
```

Which would produce something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM relationships as Relationship 
  WHERE Relationship.partyone IS NOT NULL
  AND Relationship.partytwo = 'fieldvalue';
```

Debug `$check` to understand what value is being sent to your validation message, and debug the find results to see the results. Also, look at the SQL log to see the SQL it generated. This should give you a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `pra_cake`.`relationships_users` AS `Relationship` LEFT JOIN `pra_cake`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Relationship`.`partyone` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `Relationship`.`partyone` IS NOT NULL AND `Relationship`.`partytwo` = 'boots'


the problem with this code is that its not validating at all. its saying that they both have a relationship together in the table but they dont

Comment: how can i set partyone = to the biller?

Comment: if i set relationship.partyone=>current($check) as well as partytwo it works

Comment: Glad you got it working :) I wasn't sure what data you wanted to check so I was just giving an overall perspective on how it works.

Comment: i have one more quick question, how can I compare Relationship.expirydate is more than datecreated in the invoice

Comment: Try `'DATE(Relationship.expirydate) > DATE(Relationship.datecreated)'` as a condition.

Comment: Join (use containable or recursive) the Invoice model data in then.

Answer (score 0):

What version of CakePHP are you using?

Anyway, you don't need the "public $useTable = 'invoices';", since your table's name is the Model name pluralized.
You also don't need "public $primaryKey = 'id';", since it's 'id' by default.

[check this link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html)

Comment: 2.x which is the current version

Comment: thank you for the tip, but it still has not solved my issue with the database.

Comment: @user1417448 Could you elaborate a bit your problem and post some code? Like, you "Relationship" model.

Comment: included my relationship model.

I'm just trying to see if the to/biller are in the relationship table under the columns partyone/partytwo. the issue I'm having is that even if two people are in relationship table, its coming back saying they are not in the table